# psql: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i cloned from github a docker-mail repository "https://github.com/1it/docker-mail" and ran the docker-compose.yml.
It created 6 containers and 6 images.
Then i have created a Dockerfile with a basis Image from one of these 6 Images "dockermail_roundcube", to have only one Image which contains all services.

That are the created images from Github:

```
 dockermail_dovecot        latest              451da418d747        5 days ago          160MB
 dockermail_roundcube      latest              41b2a49d9233        5 days ago          346MB
 dockermail_postfixadmin   latest              b4e1db428c5c        5 days ago          276MB
 dockermail_postfix        latest              21e6c1321a4f        5 days ago          207MB
 dockermail_certs          latest              9fa00330df3e        5 days ago          140MB
 dockermail_postgres       latest              cdfa8642ac29        5 days ago          269MB
```

then i built an image from my Dockerfile:

```
FROM dockermail_roundcube:latest
MAINTAINER Siamak Mottaghian
#Postfix
ENV DOMAIN=trivadis.com
ENV MAILNAME=smtp.trivadis.com
ENV MY_NETWORKS=172.16.0.0/15-192.168.0.0/16
# Postgres
ENV LANG=en_US.utf8
ENV DB_NAME=mail
ENV USER_NAME=mail
ENV USER_PASSWD=eeheiThoh2mohjou
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=oejoojo9eimeeloocuCogichoove4oho
ENV PG_PASSWD_FILE=postgres:5432:*:usrname:passwd
# Roundcube / Postfixadmin
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
# Roundcube config
ENV DEFAULT_HOST=ssl://imap.trivadis.com
ENV DEFAULT_PORT=993
ENV SMTP_SERVER=tls://smtp.trivadis.com
ENV SMTP_PORT=587
ENV DES_KEY=angahth3ki7shaeTie7queibeSaeyugi 
### Postfixadmin
# Sample Admin passwd
# admin@example.com
# example12345
EXPOSE 25 465 587 110 995 143 993 80 8080
```

After running the container:

```
docker run -d --name roundcube roundcube
```

i tried to open the roundcube client in browser but that is not possible.

and i get this Massage in my docker logs:

```
psql: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
```

Can you guys help me to solve that issue!?
THX

Comment: please run `docker ps -a` to check which container running

Comment: to check which container is running:   'docker ps'

        `4e7cfff7dd9c        roundcube           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          25/tcp, 80/tcp, 110/tcp, 143/tcp, 465/tcp, 587/tcp, 993/tcp, 995/tcp, 8080/tcp   roundcube`

Comment: seem the existing container only `roundcube`. Container for `postgres` should be exist there. How do you run `docker-compose`? Could you let me know?

Comment: i dont use docker-compose. i build the image via Dockerfile, mentioned above:   `docker build -t roundcube .`   
and run the container with :  `docker run -d --name roundcube roundcube`.
how you can see above in the Dockerfile i use   `FROM dockermail_roundcube:latest`

Comment: @guguli did you find out why this error happens?

Comment: @guguli Hi could you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a workaround, but the most obvious solution is to use `docker-compose`. [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) will fire up both the postgres container and your server container. Docker compose will also create a network for both of these container, so you will be able to connect to them.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same issue while migrating python/django db. you need to use sudo in unix systems, if you are running winodws, then open Powershell as an administrator or the IDE as an Admin.

```
sudo python3 manage.py migrate
```

and for winodws

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Assuming everything is in admin mode.